# Populate textboxes based on id searched

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Okay, so i am new to ajax and mvc. i have a form which requires me to enter an id in the field and after clicking the search button it retrieves and populates data from the database and displays it in the textfields.

Comment: Could you please share some code that you tried to get your desire results.

Comment: @TAB Please see the code below that i have shared.

Answer (score 0):

Controller Code

```
    public ActionResult LoadVendorInfo(string vendornumber)
    {
        var query = from c in db.Vendors
                    where c.VendorNumber == vendornumber
                    select c;
        return Json(query.FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#searchvendor").click(function () {
                            var vendornumber = $('#vendornumber').val();
                            $.ajax({
                                cache: 'false',
                                type: "POST",
                                data: { "vendornumber": vendornumber },
                                url: '@Url.Action("LoadVendorInfo", "Vendors")',
                                datatype: 'json',
                                "success": function (data) {
                                    if (data != null) {
                                        var vdata = data;
                                        $("#companyname").val(vdata[0].companyname);
                                        $("#regnum").val(vdata[0].regnum);
                                        $("#email").val(vdata[0].email);
                                        $("#contactnum").val(vdata[0].contactnum);
                                        $("#refnum").val(vdata[0].refnum);
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        })
                    })
```